# Scalable Pattern for large Feature Splits in git-flow tracked project?

Tags: git, devops, git-flow

I am in charge of infrastructure for a project that consists of a large repository including submodules.

The project team successfully implements git-flow (as described [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)) to support versioned releases. For shorthand reference, that's `develop`, `master`, and `staging-$version` branches. Day-to-day work feature branches out and into `develop`.

Sometimes multiple releases occur simultaneously, and often multiple versions require support simultaneously.

I now need to support a split in this model for a large hardware integrated feature (i.e. supporting a new wifi chip). For regulatory reasons, a feature toggle is insufficient. I need to support a version of this project where **no wifi functionality is built or included in source**. The source must be available and traceable to the final binary release. Is this dumb? Yes. Can I do anything about it? No. Negotiating with the FCC is above my paygrade.

Non-wifi related work must still be included in both the wifi and non-wifi versions of the project.

The naive solution is a set of branches like this:

- `develop`
- `develop-wifi`
- `master`
- `master-wifi`
- `staging-$version` (can now branch from either `develop` or `develop-wifi`)

With one-way only merges from `develop`->`develop-wifi` handling unrelated development.

Obviously this does not scale. What happens when in 6 months we need to support bluetooth, but that means a wifi-only, bluetooth-only, wifi+bluetooth, AND RF-free version of the project?

Against all odds :), I have carved out time to design for this problem in advance, but I am coming up short on a good scalable model to support large feature splits like this. Perhaps there isn't a good answer (this is pushing the scope of git). All my searching on this topic is turning up results confounded with git-flow tutorials and managing feature branches as typical where the expectation is everything moves upstream.

Can anyone recommend a good pattern for handling this in a more scalable fashion?

Comment: Is it possible to put the wi-fi "functionality" in a package? Then perhaps the hooks could be in the shared source, as long as it can't possibly work without the package being included? Then you could build the package in a separate repo, sub-module, etc. You could do the same for all features with similar requirements. This is sort of like a feature flag but without the code included when the flag is on. You would need the flag on *and* the package.

Comment: BTW, I don't think your naive solution is *that* bad. Regardless of what branching strategy you use you're going to have a similar issue, if you indeed end up having to create long-lived "feature" branches.

Answer (score 0):

Best design I landed on after seeking clarity on the regulations we must comply with is to insert compile time feature flags.

So this is an end-around answer to the question, but ended up being most applicable to our specific use case. TTT's comment about building the feature functionality in as an optional package is effectively the same architecture with an extra level of abstraction I think, but luckily, the compliance team isn't *actually* that arbitrary.

I still did not find a good branch centric solution, so I will leave this question open, but it would seem that the concept of "applying the same patch to two ever more divergent branches" doesn't really make sense at a core level, so I'm not optimistic that there's a good solution in there.